# Inequality of skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

> Let $A$ be a  $n\times n$ skew-symmetric real matrix.Prove that
>
> $\forall v \in \mathbb{R^n}　\ \|(E-A)v\| \geq \|v \| $
>
> where $\|v\|$ is the Euclid norm of $v$ and $E$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

I have no idea. How to prove this inequality? Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, $$\|(E-A)v\|^2=((E-A)v)^T(E-A)v=v^T(E-A)^T(E-A)v.$$

Using skew symmetry,
$$v^T(E-A)^T(E-A)v=v^T(E-A^T-A+A^TA)v=v^T(E+A^TA)v=v^Tv+(Av)^T(Av).$$

The first term is just $\|v\|^2$, while the second is always $\ge 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Just expand the scalar product $\langle (E-A)v,(E-A)v \rangle$ and use skew symmetry.